# Certain classes do not show up in JDB while they are present in source code

Tags: android, java, apk

I'm debugging a closed-source Android app with `jdb`. In the output produced by the `apktool`, I see class `com.myapp.j.d.d`, as well as a/b/c/e, but at run-time, I see only `com.myapp.j.d.e`. Why is that happening?

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is that the classes fail verification. If this is the case, when you install the apk, you'll see messages from art in logcat with details about which class failed verification and why.

Comment: `logcat` reports nothing about this app. It must be something else!

Comment: Most class verification happens when the apk is installed. Are you sure you're looking at logcat while the apk is being installed, rather than when running the app?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that in 4.4+ ART is AOT. Reinstalled the app, but `logcat` is still silent

Comment: Well, that was the case even in dalvik :). If there's no verification error, then I don't know why the class wouldn't be present.

Comment: Dynamic loading and unloading of the class during the execution?

Comment: afaik, ART doesn't support class unloading.

Comment: Should I check the output of `pm` during the initial installation of the apk?